# Access AWS CloudFormation ARN from inside Lambda Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, aws-cloudformation, aws-lambda

I have two Lambda Functions Lambda1 and Lambda2. Lambda1 does some work and sends multiple results to Lambda2 via an SNS Topic called Topic1. Lambda2 then processes the results of Lambda1.

```
Lambda1 -> Topic1 -> Lambda2
```

This all works well until I try to build a CloudFormation Template that represents it. I can subscribe Lambda2 to Topic1, but how can I tell Lambda1 which SNS topic to push messages to? After all the topic ARN is not created until the CloudFormation Stack is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use single `CloudFormation` stack to create this scenario. Outputs of your stack can be used to configure `Lambda 1` created within the stack to access `Topic 1`, you just need to give your `Lambda` `cloudformation:DescribeStacks` permission and then access your stack outputs from your `Lambda` code.

Comment: Thanks for this. I haven't marked it as the correct answer yet because I haven't had time to try it. Looks good though.

Comment: Yes this is it. I created the stack, got the ARNs from the  cloudformation::DescribeStacks (actually boto3.resource('cloudformation').StackResource), stored the ARNs in an S3 bucket and got the lambda functions to load the ARNs from there.